# Attempting to connect to remote server with SFTP but receiving a needless passphrase prompt

Tags: ubuntu, ssh, terminal, authentication, sftp

I recently made the switch from Windows to Ubuntu for development and I have problems trying to setup a connection to a remote server.

On Windows, I use cyberduck to connect to a remote server through SFTP with an unprotected keyfile.

So now I am trying to sftp in with the command line doing this:

```
sudo sftp -o IdentityFile=< location of my keyfile > < myusername >@< myhostname >
```

And I get back this response:

```
Enter passphrase for key < my keyfile >: 
Permission denied (publickey).
Couldn't read packet: Connection reset by peer
```

I use the **exact** same key file to connect on Windows and it works without issue. I am never prompted to enter a passphrase because this particular keyfile does not have a passphrase and, unfortunately, I cannot replace it with a keyfile that does have a passphrase, because this was provided to me by my employer.

My keyfile's permissions are set to 600 and it is a `ppk` file.

What is going on here? What can I do to get connected?

Comment: IIRC, key format for putty/winscp/pscp is different from ssh/sftp client key format.  Once you get your key(s) working, skip the SFTP and just use sshfs :)

Comment: See for example [How to convert SSH keypairs generated using PuttyGen(Windows) into key-pairs used by ssh-agent and KeyChain(Linux)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2224204/4440445) or [How to convert .ppk key to OpenSSH key under Linux?](https://superuser.com/a/232365/549309)

Comment: What does your key file look like? Show us its format.

Comment: I believe `ssh` and friends (e.g. `sftp`) check the permission (600 as you mentioned, that's okay) and the owner of the key file as well. Since you're running it as `root` (via `sudo`), the referred file should be owned by `root`. It might even check the ownership of its containing directory, I'm not sure about it. (By the way, why do you use `sudo` at all?)